# Turn off iCloud on iPhone without removing Apple-ID

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, apple-id

When I created Apple-ID on iPhone (iOS 15) and then went to "Settings > Account name", there was "off" in iCloud line.

Then I tapped this line and followed instructions to create iCloud binding for the Apple-ID now knowing what will come next.

What came next is that there is constantly "5 GB" displayed in iCloud line and I can't turn it off again.

All the instructions on removing iCloud from iPhone found by me in Internet suggest to sign out from Apple-ID. But I do not want to sign off from Apple-ID! I just want the original state with "iCloud ..... off".
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the On/Off state for iCloud, there are also individual On/Off sliders for every service (or app) that makes use of iCloud.

So if your concern is about putting data in the cloud, simply make sure all those services/apps are off.

Comment: I am concerned that these switches are turned on by default for every newly installed application and some "system backups" cannot be turned off at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use Apple ID without iCloud on your iPhone:

1. Sign out of Apple ID in Settings (incl. iCloud)
2. Sign in to Apple ID in the App Store (NOT in Settings!)